# Webm video format doesn't work on safari (ios)

Tags: javascript

The following problem only exists on iOS devices and with webm format. Don't say that it works when you open example on sandbox. To test it , open it on real iOS devices (sandbox example, see button below).

```
 <video
      id="video-which-do-not-want-to-work"
      autoplay
      loop
      muted
      playsinline
      width="400"
      height="300"
      src="https://dl8.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm"
    ></video>
```

Here is what I've tried:

1. Play it without `autoplay`
2. All examples which I found on stack says that you should add `playsinline` and `muted`
3. Tried to use `source` inside of `video` tag with `webm` type
4. Tried to imitate button click

```
 const button = document.createElement('button')

 button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('video-which-do-not-want-to-work').play()
 })

 button.click()
```

5. Also tried to add real button in html and attach `onclick` event function , which execute `element.play()`
6. Checked that "Low power mode" switched off on my phone

iOS version of device: 15.5

What can I try to fix this?

Code example:

[image: Edit cranky-hugle-vf16ro]

Comment: does [caniuse webm](https://caniuse.com/webm) help? there seems to be some "conditions" with webm in safari

Comment: I cannot get this to work in neither Chrome Nor Safari on iOS [video](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vaLjgr75/show) - it works on desktop Chrome Windows

Comment: @Bravo I see some partial support and some info about codecs , but I don't understand is it possible to play it ? could you give more info pls ?

Comment: yes @mplungjan , but on Android it will work

Comment: @mplungjan should I change description that it also doesn't work chrome ?

Comment: chrome in ios is not chrome - so don't bother changing the question - the issue is purely safari (I think in IOS, "chrome" is basically safari pig with chrome lipstick)

Comment: What I inferred from the limitations on caniuse is that webm is supported in WebRTC, not video tag (I could be wrong though - that's why I posted a link rather than an opinion)

Comment: having read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) there's absolutely NO mention of webm - oops, sorry, that's 10 years old - search for something more recent

Comment: yes @Bravo there is also exist this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari , but it also isn't really helpful

Comment: what codecs are used in your webm? what version of safari? (pre 14.1 is probably a no go)

Comment: @Bravo I've attached ios version to description , but how to get video codec , I don't know , maybe you can help find out how to get it from url attached to description ?

Comment: @Bravo  `IOS version of device: 15.5`

Comment: [MetaData2Go](https://www.metadata2go.com/result/49896e98-e28c-4ceb-9fbd-d47aaac560f4) says vp8 video and Vorbis audio and caniuse says that is supported by your device

Comment: @mplungjan and it still doesn't work ) magic )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video even if you will open mdn doc and  will find first example there , and will remove this line <source src="/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4"
            type="video/mp4"> , it will also doesn't work on ios device , but when mp4 included it works )

Answer (score 0):

Webm format is not supported by iOS (may be in the new version after "iphone 14" it is supported but not before.) So, what we can do is to convert webm file into a file foramt like mp4 which is supported by android as well as ios. Try to use server side to convert webm video into mp4 and then play the converted mp4 video on client side.

Use fluent-ffmpeg or that kind of library to convert webm to mp4. Here is a sample code in node.js.

```
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const fs = require("fs");

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

// Input and output file paths
const inputFilePath =
  "input/file/path/or/url.mp4";
const outputFilePath = "output/file/path";

// Create a FFmpeg command
const command = ffmpeg();

// Set input file
command.input(inputFilePath);

// Set video codec to libx264 (MP4)
command.videoCodec("libx264");

// Set fps (30 makes the conversion fast)
command.outputFPS(30);

// Set output file
command.output(outputFilePath);

// Run the conversion
command
  .on("end", () => {
    console.log("Conversion finished.");
  })
  .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    console.error("ffmpeg stdout:", stdout);
    console.error("ffmpeg stderr:", stderr);
  })
  .run();
```